# Test a ZIP file if data has been added at the end of the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, verification

I am searching for a way to test ZIP files for more details as Pythons `ZipFile.testzip()` does.

In detail I am searching a way to identify ZIP files that have been modified in a way that somebody has appended additional data after the end of the ZIP file - or to be precise after the end of the [End of central directory record (EOCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#End_of_central_directory_record_(EOCD)).

Common zip testing tools (Python `ZipFile.testzip()`, unzip, 7zip, WinRAR, ...) only test the file up to the EOCD and ignore additional data afterwards. However I need to know if there is additional data present or not after the end of the EOCD.

Is there a simple way to do so in Python? The simplest way would be if I could read the real "ZIP file size" (the offset of the last byte of the EOCD + 1). But how can this be done in Python?